# In netbeans 12.4 maven javafx project I ran git rm and git restore on files in /target/class and now get maven error on run so how do I fix?

Tags: git, maven, javafx, netbeans, graalvm

After executing git rm and git restore on some files in only the /target/class folder in a NetBeans 12.4 maven javafx project that also uses graalvm, I then attempted to run the project using Run Project icon and get the error that javafx runtime components are missing. The maven debug report contains no information about the specific components that are missing.

This error is thrown when maven reports it is "Executing command line" and the command line is given as "C:\graalvm-ce-java16-21.2.0\bin\java.exe, -classpath, ...."  The ellipsis is a long list of directories and files, all of which I have checked and verified are in my project.

The first entry after "classpath," is "C:\Users\don\Documents\GWP\GUIWeb\target\classes", and this is the folder in which I ran git rm and git restore commands. But there is still a corresponding  .class file in the project's target/class folder for every .java class in my NetBeans Projects panel. The maven error report does not specify any file names subsequent to reporting the error. It merely gives a long list of file line numbers that were executed.

Is there anything I can do to get maven to stop throwing this error?

Comment: You have described your problem in considerable detail, and explained why you believe you are doing everything correctly, but there is no output in this question for anyone to review. Where is the output from your restore? Where is the output from your Run? Where is the output from your Maven debug? Were are your screen shots? Where is your version information for Maven, Java and JavaFX? Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how you can reasonably expect a solution to your problem based on the information provided.

Comment: Can you run `mvn clean`?

Comment: Yes. I ran mvn clean build and it worked fine. I tried running the program using the java cli command and that failed too.

Comment: I believe I made it quite clear to any reader of my problem that maven reported that it was "Executing command line" and the command line is given as "C:\graalvm-ce-java16-21.2.0\bin\java.exe, -classpath, ....". However the following reporting by maven is useless in that it does not tell anyone what files are missing. graalvm's java.exe was executing and failed. One obvious question would be "Does java.exe make entries in a log file somewhere?" I have not been able to find out via google searches. But clearly java.exe did not find one or more of the files, but which one('s)?

Comment: In fact, based on the above I will ask a new question if anyone knows where graalvm java.exe log files are and where and how/where one can learn how to configure the log file if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be quite simple. Just execute "mvn -X javafx:run" in a CLI. This command simply ignores the contents of the target/class directory and generates all the files in target/class anew. The program runs without errors. However, subsequent use of the methods to run the project within NetBeans 12.4 DO NOT WORK. But I can easily live with that until I learn how to fix what's going on in NetBeans (IF I ever even want to).